# Puedo poner un vídeo de fondo en un index.php?

Tags: php, video

la duda es la del título, en un index.html no tengo problemas y se ejecuta el vídeo sin problemas, pero en un archivo php, con la misma sintaxis no me está agarrando el vídeo.
El código que tengo es este:

```
<body>
    <?php require "partials/header.php" ?>
    <video autoplay preload="auto" loop>
        <source src="estilos/imagenes/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video>
```

La idea es tenerlo de fondo y un login que estoy haciendo ponerlo encima. No sé si simplemente en un archivo php hacer este tipo de cosas no es posible.
No sé exactamente que poner en internet para conseguir una solución, si tenéis algún enlace que aclare mi duda lo veo con gusto.
Un saludo.

Comment: *no me está agarrando el video* no es una descripción clara del error. ¿Has revisado la consola del navegador por posibles mensajes de error?

Comment: Hola, me muestra como el primer fotograma del vídeo, pero pausado, no reproduce nada, sin embargo el mismo código en un archivo html, no tengo ese problema y se reproduce el vídeo correctamente, he revisado la consola y está limpia. Ningún mensaje de error

Comment: En el navegador revisa el código fuente de la página `index.php` y revisa que sea igual al que tienes en `index.html`.

Comment: @Triby solucionado, me he estado leyendo un poco sobre el funcionamiento, y resulta que si no pongo el atributo muted en la etiqueta video, chrome no reproduce el video

Answer (score 0):

Los navegadores modernos no permiten la reproducción automática de un video si no tiene la opción "muted" declarada, cambia simplemente esto en tu código y debería funcionar

```
<body>
<?php require "partials/header.php" ?>
<video autoplay muted preload="auto" loop>
    <source src="estilos/imagenes/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```